# Excel Text Box Character Limitation

Tags: microsoft-excel, characters

In my excel workbook, WORKSHEET1 has a text box that contains the formula =SHEET2!B25. The text in the text box cuts off at 255 characters. If I create a 2nd text box on WORKSHEET1 and just enter text, I can go well beyond 250 characters.

Is there any workaround to the 255 character limit when using a formula in the text box to get text from another worksheet?

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the text box when in Design mode (on the Developer tab), and select 'Properties'. In the Properties dialog, set Max Length to 0.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can get the worksheet properties, but I can't get the text box properties. If I right-click on the text box and select the properties beside the design mode I get the worksheet properties dialog box as shown. If I right-click on the text box and select the "Size and Properties" from the drop-down menu, I just get the standard window for formatting the text box.
[Properties Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03XXh.jpg)

I figured out the problem. I had inserted a text box using the INSERT tab / Insert text Box, not the DEVELOPER tab, Insert, Active X / Text Box.
Doing it this way I do get all of the text, but I lose the (bulleted) numbered list I had in the original text box. I don't see any way in the text box properties to have a numbered list within the Active X text box.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot come right with the string length using a text box, then you can also try the camera command in the newer versions of Excel.

1. Place the cursor on the cell you want to display.
2. Select the camera
3. Go to the place in your workbook & click on the sheet
4. Press enter
5. it will display the cell in a window (similar to a text box)

You may need to include the camera function in the ribbon, for which you need to go to File/Options/Customize Ribbon/All Commands/Add>>